# Change displayed URL to show index.php in place of two other file names

Tags: regex, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm really not into regular expression and I have trouble to set a rule for my website.

I have two index files, named `index-pc.php` and a second named `index-mob.php`, and I want to be able to hide the `-pc/-mob` part of the filename. Which syntax I should use to do so?

My current rule is:

```
RewriteEngine On    
RewriteRule ^index-(pc|mob)\.php$ index.php [L]
```

But this rule is not working. What I'm missing?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The regex seems to be correct. Did you enabled .htaccess already? If not, open your httpd.conf and change

```
<Directory />
  ....
  AllowOverride None
</Directory>
```

to

```
<Directory />
  ....
  AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

Comment: Thank you for answering.

It wasn't related to this but just to a wrong order of things in my `.htaccess`

But my issue is now the `mod_rewrite` make a redirection and then it's not working. This lead to a 404 error...There in fact **no** `index.php` file there, I want just to show a replacement name to hide the `-pc`or `-mob` part in the address.